# What type of actuators are needed for a high accuracy, low load weight robotic arm?

Tags: robotic-arm, servomotor, stepper-motor, actuator, precise-positioning

I am trying to build a robotic arm that needs to lift a very low amount of weight (between 0.01-0.05kg) at a time, but it needs to be very precise (+/- 1mm accuracy ideally). The robot really only needs to have 3 DOF and the arc is roughly 0.5 meters. Additionally, the robot doesn't need to be very fast, only around 0.2-0.5 m/s is necessary.

What type of actuator would be the best suited for this kind of task, and what other factors would I have to consider? Do I need to spend more money for high quality servos, or can the task be done with hobby/RC servos with some modifications?

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself if you really need [accuracy or precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision).  Because I think precision is easier to achieve than accuracy for most arms.

I am not sure I would be as worried about the actuator as the gear-train and sensing.  Here are some back of the envelope calculations to illustrate:

At 0.5 meters, to achieve an error of 1 mm, that is $asin(1/500) = 0.1146^\circ$.  (And there will probably be an elbow halfway down the arm with similar backlash, compounding the error).  You probably want your gear train to have a backlash less than that or else you will have a hard time controlling the arm.

To sense this error, your joint encoder will need a resolution of $360^\circ/0.1146^\circ = 3141.6$ ticks/rev.  And you will really want these joint encoders **after** the gear train to be able to measure and account of the above mentioned backlash.

Thankfully, your payloads are light, so arm sag is probably not a concern.